# How to visulize data in Bro network security monitor

Tags: visualization, bro

I have configured [Bro Network Security Monitor](https://www.bro.org/) on my Linux system.In logs directory, different logs are maintained by Bro. In each file, data is in tsv form. I have to visualize this data for better usage and monitoring. I think Bro does not provide any builtin visualization tool. Is there any tool that can be used for this purpose ?

Comment: Have a look at AfterGlow (http://afterglow.sf.net), as well as at http://secviz.org - You will find a bunch of information on both sites that should get you going.